# how to solve?Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSProgressIndicator'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsprogressindicator

Hi how can i solve it here is my *.h file:may i include somethink? i have found that i have to `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>` but  i do not even find AppKit framework

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CrossViewController.h"
#import "NavTestAppDelegate.h"
#import "Obrat1.h"
#import "Event.h"
#import "StvrtyViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"


@interface TretiViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    UILabel *testLabel;
    UILabel *acBallanceLable;
    UILabel *acNumberLable;
    UILabel *accCurrencyLabel;
    NSString *ibaTestFix;
    UITableView *tView;
    NSMutableArray *other;
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController_;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;  //here it falls
```

Thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone/UIKit does not offer the NSProgressIndicator class.  That is for Mac OS X programming.

You want UIProgressIndicator, IIRC.